# How to calibrate Garmin Vector 2 power meter pedals with a Wahoo Elemnt computer?

Tags: road-bike, maintenance, power, garmin, ant+

I just installed Garmin Vector 2 power meter pedals on my bike along and am using it alongside a Wahoo Elemnt bike computer. I've done a few rides now and my average wattage is reading very high (i.e. avg watts with garmin is ~257 vs. ~135 when I was just using the Strava iphone app).

I've updated my Garmin Vector and Wahoo Elemnt so that it's running on the current versions. Any other suggestions on how to get a more accurate wattage reading? Is there a separate calibration process that I need to go through? Do you think my pedals need to be re-torqued?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In general, specific questions like this are best asked on either the Garmin or Wahoo support forums. Nonetheless, have you "set the installation angle" by pedaling at 80-90 rpm for 30 seconds *before* trying "calibrate" on the Elemnt?

Answer (score 4):

It seems others were having this same issue and it turned out to be the torque not being set to specs (Garmin recommends a torque of 25 to 30 lbf-ft (34 to 40 N-m).

In my case, I had skipped a step in the Wahoo calibration. Here's the fix:

1.) turn your pedals 1 rotation so that the pedal pods blink 5 times in a row (this means garmin is ready to be calibrated).
2.) Turn on your Wahoo Elemnt by pressing and holding the power button. Once on, press (but don't hold) the power button to get the to the GPS/Sensors screen. Select your sensor and in the bottom left corner you should see CALIB. Press that and it will complete the process.

I just got back from a 3mi test ride and my watts went from 257w to 118w (which is much more accurate!).

Hope this helps!